# How can I load a PHP page into an element with its js files included?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var HOST = "<?php Print(HOST); ?>";
        $(".icon_sisconbr-icons-pedidos").click(function() {
            $("body").load(HOST + "index.php/pedido/novo");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The page loads fine, but none of the functionality works (The JS files attached to the original file that work when accessed through a link). All pages have a "head" with all the links to bootstrap and so on. I try to load them before loading the content:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var HOST = "<?php Print(HOST); ?>";
        $(".icon_sisconbr-icons-pedidos").click(function() {
            $("html").load("../../estrutura/head.php");
            $("body").load(HOST + "index.php/pedido/novo");
        });
    });
</script>
```

But it does not work. I don't understand the "timing" of these inclusions. I know that .load() is ajax and works async, but I don't understand why the JS files used by the page are not loaded as well.

Comment: On your browser open developers tools (Google Chrome F12) and click on Network Tab to check the timing loading pages

Comment: Really useful!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the second `.load()` command inside the "complete" callback of the first (so that it runs only after the first one has been loaded successfully):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var HOST = "<?php Print(HOST); ?>";
     $(".icon_sisconbr-icons-pedidos").click(function() {
         $("html").load("../../estrutura/head.php", function() {
            $("body").load(HOST + "index.php/pedido/novo"); 
         });
     });
});
```